# XAML: Flowdocument - Content cut after one page in XPS

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, flowdocument, xps

I have a problem using `FlowDocument` control.

Here is my XAML code:

```
<FlowDocument>
...

  <Paragraph Margin="0" KeepTogether="true">
    <Grid Width="710" >
      <StackPanel Margin="20,0" x:Name="CommentStackA" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <TextBlock x:Name="CommentAHead" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=l10nDentistCommentHeader}" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Blue" Margin="0,5"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="CommentA" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=dentistComment}" Margin="0,1"/>
      </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
  </Paragraph>
  <Paragraph Margin="0">
    <Grid Width="710" >
      <StackPanel Margin="20,0" x:Name="CommentStackB" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <TextBlock x:Name="CommentBHead" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=l10nLabCommentHeader}" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Blue" Margin="0,5"/>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <TextBlock x:Name="CommentBCompanyName" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=comment_LabCompanyName}"/>
          <TextBlock x:Name="Spacer" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text=" - "/>
          <TextBlock x:Name="CommentBName" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=comment_LabUsername}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock x:Name="CommentB" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=labComment}" Margin="0,1"/>
      </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
  </Paragraph>
</FlowDocument>
```

I use this code as a template for generating XPS-files. The problem is that in case the first comment (CommentA) is very long it is cut at the end of the first page.

How can I get that first paragraph not to be cut but shown over two pages?

Comment: How do you generate XPS file from FlowDocument?

Comment: We use the method described in this blog entry by Brad Curtis. [link](http://www.bradcurtis.com/document-and-report-generation-using-xaml-wpf-data-binding-and-xps/)